# Restructuring team data with duplicate individual entries in R

Tags: r

My current data set looks like this:

```
Person  Team1     Team2     Team3   Team4   Team5
  1      10         11       NA      NA      NA  
  2      12         13       14      NA      NA
  3      15         16       NA      NA      NA
  1      11         14       NA      NA      NA
```

As you can see, some people (i.e., person 1) repeat throughout the data set.  Duplicate entries for a given person may provide new information on team affiliation, and may also repeat old information.  What I would like to do is create a data set where each individual only occupies a single row, and the information on their team membership is all contained within that row, and is not redundant.  For instance:

```
Person  Team1   Team2   Team3   Team4   Team5
  1      10      11      14      NA      NA
  2      12      13      14      NA      NA
  3      15      16      NA      NA      NA
```

So, even though person 1 was listed as being on team 11 twice in the data set, it only appears once in the final version.  FYI: the team variables go all the way to 16 in my actual data set, rather than stopping at 5.

Comment: Unfortunately, @waxattax needs to merge the rows in an awkward way - not *just* remove duplicate entries.

Comment: Look into dplyr `yourdf %.% group_by(Person)`, it does this more elegantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another possibility. There will be elegant ways to do this. But this gives you the outcome you requested. First, I split the data by `Person` and created a vector for each person. Second, I searched unique elements in each vector and made the length `length(colnames(mydf))-1` . Third, I converted a list to a data frame. Finally, I added a column for `Person` and changed the column names.

```
ana <- lapply(split(mydf, mydf$Person), function(x) c(as.matrix(x[,-1])))
bob <- lapply(lapply(ana, unique), function(y) y[1:length(colnames(mydf))-1])
cathy <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, bob))
dan <- cbind(unique(mydf$Person), cathy)
names(dan) <- names(mydf)

#  Person Team1 Team2 Team3 Team4 Team5
#1      1    10    11    14    NA    NA
#2      2    12    13    14    NA    NA
#3      3    15    16    NA    NA    NA
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(Person = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), Team1 = c(10L, 12L, 
15L, 11L), Team2 = c(11L, 13L, 16L, 14L), Team3 = c(NA, 14L, 
NA, NA), Team4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), Team5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Person", 
"Team1", "Team2", "Team3", "Team4", "Team5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: This seemed to work, except it resulted in a data frame with only 5 "team" columns, when in actuality there should be more.  My example is simplified, but my actual data has more columns for team identification codes.  Sorry for any misunderstanding!  Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: In the current data set there are 16 columns for teams, but because there are duplicate entries for certain individuals (and some duplicate entries contain differing information) it's possible that there are people that participated in more than 16 teams.

Comment: @waxattax Thanks for that. Since you seem to want to remove duplicated entries (e.g., 11 for Person 1 appeared twice, but you count once), the max number of team would be 16, no matter what. Is that correct?

Comment: @waxattax I revised my suggestion. Please have a look and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `data.table`.  Convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" by `setDT`, change from "wide" to "long" form, get the `unique` values of the "Team" columns by "Person", (`unique(unlist(.SD))`), create the sequence column ("V2") per each "Person", and reshape it back to "wide" by `dcast.data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- dcast.data.table(setDT(df)[, unique(unlist(.SD)) ,
          by=Person][, V2:=paste0('Team', 1:.N), by=Person],
                                Person~V2, value.var='V1')
dt1 
 #  Person Team1 Team2 Team3 Team4
 #1:      1    10    11    14    NA
 #2:      2    12    13    14    NA
 #3:      3    15    16    NA    NA
```

If you need "Team5", "Team6", etc, create a vector of the the "Team" names, use `setdiff`, and then assign the result vector to `NA`

```
indx <- setdiff(paste0('Team', 1:5), colnames(dt1))
dt1[,(indx):=NA]
dt1
#   Person Team1 Team2 Team3 Team4 Team5
#1:      1    10    11    14    NA    NA
#2:      2    12    13    14    NA    NA
#3:      3    15    16    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Much shorter. I like it. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super well-versed in R, so this code may be sloppy, but I think your best bet here is going to be creating a new column that contains a list of team memberships, e.g.:

```
data$teams = with(data, c(Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4[...]))
```

Where [...] is the rest of the teams.  From there, you could probably aggregate the columns, using `Person` as a key, and do some unlisting/uniqueing to eliminate duplicates:

```
byperson = aggregate(data, by=list(data$Person), FUN=list)
byperson$teams = sapply(sapply(byperson$teams, unlist), unique)
```

Which aggregates the list by person, combining duplicate rows (the lists I made in the first bit) with the `list` function, which makes a list of lists.  The second line then just goes through each of the lists-of-lists in byperson$teams, first runs `unlist` on them to get them into one flat list, and then `unique` to get rid of dupes.

There are probably better and more elegant ways to do this, perhaps with the `melt` library, but that's the basic idea you're gonna have to do - reformat the 16 columns into either one column of lists, or expand it out into rows, one for each "membership"  This latter format is what R tends to "prefer" in my experience, something like this:

```
Person Team
     1   10
     1   11
     1   14
     2   12
     2   13
     2   14
     3   15
     3   16
```

But I'm not sure how to get there from your data.  The list of lists may be amenable, depending on what you're trying to do with the data, but the data as it is structured in your example is going to be really difficult to do anything useful with in R.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the `cast`/`melt` functions from the `reshape2` package

```
library(reshape2)

# Make the data tidy
d.melt <- melt(mydf,id.vars = 'Person')

# Remove duplicates
d.uniq <- d.melt[!duplicated(d.melt[,c('Person','value')]),]

# renumber the teams
d.uniq$team <- ave(d.uniq$Person,d.uniq$Person,FUN=function(i) paste0('Team',seq_along(i)))

# cast into the desired 'wide' format
d.result <- dcast(d3,Person~team,value.var = 'value')
```

The result is:

```
#   Person Team1 Team2 Team3 Team4
# 1      1    10    11    14    NA
# 2      2    12    13    14    NA
# 3      3    15    16    NA    NA
```

If the result has to have certain number of columns:

```
all.teams <- paste0('Team',1:16)
d.result[,all.teams[!all.teams %in% colnames(d.result)]]=NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

```
x <- read.table(text = "Person  Team1     Team2     Team3   Team4   Team5
  1      10         11       NA      NA      NA  
  2      12         13       14      NA      NA
  3      15         16       NA      NA      NA
  1      11         14       NA      NA      NA", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
gather(meaningless_column, Team, -Person) %>%
select(-meaningless_column) %>%
filter(!is.na(Team)) %>%
distinct %>%
arrange(Person, Team) %>%
group_by(Person) %>%
mutate(Index = paste0("Team_", seq_along(Team))) %>%
ungroup %>%
spread(Index, Team)
```

Result:

```
  Person Team_1 Team_2 Team_3
1      1     10     11     14
2      2     12     13     14
3      3     15     16     NA
```

It will create as many `Team_n` columns as required.